# Query returning same results for Every ID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have written following Query :

```
SELECT a.propId, a.amenId, al.amenLabel 
                    FROM tblOne a 
                    JOIN tblTwo al ON a.amenId = al.id
                    JOIN tblThree p ON a.propId = p.ID
```

I have three tables

```
tblOne : mapping table in which ID (identity column), amenId, amenlLabel , PropId are stored

tblTwo : id (identity column), amenLable are stored

tblThree : ID (identity column), and other columns are stored.
```

amenLabel are stored in mapping tblOne based on propID in tblThree.

Here I am passing propId from C# code.
and based on propId, the amenLabels will be retrieved & displayed on the page for particular propId

But the issue is for each propId it's displaying same values.
kindly please look at the query.

Comment: use where condition with your select statement.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting this question?

Comment: where did you mentioned propID in the query?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a where condition with the input what you are passing through C#.
please check the following query,

```
SELECT a.propId, a.amenId, al.amenLabel 
                    FROM tblOne a 
                    JOIN tblTwo al ON a.amenId = al.id
                    JOIN tblThree p ON a.propId = p.ID
                    WHERE a.propId=@yourinput
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `where` condition, use `where` condtidion  like this

```
SELECT a.propId, a.amenId, al.amenLabel 
                    FROM tblOne a 
                    JOIN tblTwo al ON a.amenId = al.id
                    JOIN tblThree p ON a.propId = p.ID
where a.propId= :propId(this is your passed parameter)
```